# How can I push array inside array

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

I have an array and I want to put it in another array using indexes.

For example:

```
arry[1].push(sub_array_1)
array[2].push (sub_array_2)
```

But I get an error if I write:

```
var sub_array_1 = [1, 2, 2, 2, 2];

arry[1].push(sub_array_1)
```

Comment: Are you going to tell us what the error is or do we have to guess? I don't like the guessing game. In addition, what's the value of `arry` and `array`?

Comment: what is array variable?

Comment: Start off by reading the documentation for `Array#push` and array element access.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about rudimentary behavior of `push` which is easily answered by RTFM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let array = []
array.push({"index": 0, "value":100})
console.log(array)
```

maybe it helping for you

Answer (score 5):

Using spread operator

```
var subArray = [1, 4, 6, 7];
var mainArray = [6, 7, 8];
var index = 1;
mainArray = [...mainArray.slice(0, index), subArray, ...mainArray.slice(index)];
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming:

```
var arry = [9,8,7];
var sub_array_1 = [1,2,2,2,2];
```

1. If you are trying to insert `sub_array_1` into `arry`, *as a single element*, just use `splice` directly:

   ```
   arry.splice(1, 0, sub_array_1);
   ```

   The result will be:

   ```
   [9,[1,2,2,2,2],8,7]
   ```
2. On the other hand, if you are trying to insert *the contents* of `sub_array_1` before the second element of `arry`, you can do something like this:

   Array.prototype.splice.apply(arry, [1, 0].concat(sub_array_1));

   The result will be:

   ```
   [9,1,2,2,2,2,8,7]
   ```

   Here is a more general function:

   ```
   function insert(arrayDest, index, arraySrc) {
     Array.prototype.splice.apply(arrayDest, [index, 0].concat(arraySrc));
   }
   ```

   [EDITED]

   Starting with ES6, you can simplify the above code using the spread operator (`...`). For example:

   ```
   function insert(arrayDest, index, arraySrc) {
     arrayDest.splice(index, 0, ...arraySrc);
   }
   ```

Comment: Since `arry` is an array why not just us `arry.splice()`?

Comment: Because `splice` expects the inserted elements to be passed as individual values, not as an array.

Comment: Ah. I think your understanding of the question is wrong. He wants to insert the sub_array into the array. Not the contents of sub_array. If you feel that your interpretation is correct please ask the OP to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You're using wrong syntax! Follow the either below mentioned approach.

```
var sub_array_1 = [1,2,2,2,2];
arry[1] = sub_array_1;

// OR

var sub_array_1 = [1,2,2,2,2];
arry.push(sub_array_1);
```

`.push(ele)` will add an item to an array, thereby incrementing the length of array by 1. Remember array index starts at `0`.

If you need to add an item(array/object/other) to a particular index, use [index]. Eg: `arry[0] = [1,23]; arry[1] = [4,5,6,7];`

Comment: Hope it solves your problem :) Please mark it answer by ticking :)

Answer (score 0):

```
obj.arrayOne.push(arrayLetters);
```

or

```
obj['arrayOne'].push(arrayLetters);
```